# Change Cmd-Tab behavior to show the last used window on Big Sur, like it did on Mojave

Tags: macos, terminal, keyboard, mojave, big-sur

I installed Big Sur and it seems that Command-Tab changed behavior. Before, I cycled to a program and saw the last used window. Now I see some window in a predefined order. This is annoying because I usually have two open windows on Terminal, one to run programs locally and another to run them on a remote server, and I sometimes cancel or run programs in the wrong window.

I found no settings for this in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and System Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard. I suspect it's possible with something like

```
defaults write com.apple.switch order last-used
```

My question is similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1661903/in-macos-what-is-the-keyboard-shortcut-to-switch-to-the-last-used-window, except that I don't want to install a new window-switcher like HyperSwitch, just to go back to the behavior I'm used to in Mojave or High Sierra.

### Update

Here is an example. I have two Terminal windows, one local and one connected to a server. Before I cycle to another program, e.g. StackExchange to ask a question, the window on top is the local one:

[image: Terminal windows with local on top]

When I go back to Terminal, the server one is sometimes on top:

[image: Terminal windows with server on top]

And what I would like is the last one that was on top to still be on top.

The behavior does not always happen. I just tested and when the windows have nothing running, they maintain the order. When a window has something running and is printing characters, the other one becomes the top one when I cycle back to it.

Comment: Even in Mojave, it's slightly more complex than that. If all windows of the app being switched to are in the same Space, then it will bring the app to the front **and** switch to that Space if System Prefs > Mission Control > "When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for that application" is **also** on. If any of those are not true, then it will switch app but not Space. I can't check Big Sur, but I've tested this seems to be the same in Mojave and Ventura.

Comment: By space, I believe you mean what happens when watching media full-screen, and I switch to it with Control-right-arrow. Aside from media, I always use a single space only. I checked the Mission Control preferences and couldn't find a setting for showing the last used window.

Comment: There's never been a pref for last-used window. If you're trying to do all your work in one Space, do you hide windows? They won't work either.

Comment: No, I don't hide windows, and I don't expect macOS to show a hidden or minimized window. I added screenshots and an explanation in the question.

Comment: Hmmm… I'd guess that is something specific to the tasks you are running, not Finder/macOS itself. I don't ever run enough in Terminal to ever be able to test that though.

Comment: OK, thank you. Can you write an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: We don't really have an answer yet, until someone can confirm the Terminal behaviour.